# How to attach a flat file into informatica Email?

Tags: email, attachment, xls, email-attachments, informatica

I want to send a mail to some users after workflow is done. This email should contain 3 xls file or 1 xls file with 3 sheets. The xls file contains a query result -less than 50 rows- which is loaded by a task dynamically on each run of the workflow.

So in Informatica I couldn't see an option inside the "Email" task to attach anything. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send emails with attachments using the *Email* task (don't ask me why, I cannot imagine any reason for that and this is how it is).

However, **sessions can send emails** and **these emails may contain attachments** - the appropriate options are on the *Components* tab, the variable you need is `%a<>`.

More information: [How to attach new files to email task?](https://community.informatica.com/message/64518)

Answer (score 2):

cat filename  | mailx -s "subject" abc@def.com

or

use mutt command to send files as attachments

Answer (score 0):

At session level, in components tab we have option to send mail along with attachments.we have to provide path of the file as well using %a<> built in command.
Example:-
%a